# Stop Android OS font size increases affecting the font size on website

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-size

If I increase the font size in my Android phone settings, these changes seem to affect the font size on some websites and not others.

I'm currently building a site and have used the following meta properties:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`

Yet the font size is still affected in Chrome and Firefox. I want to preserve the media queries I've written too, so hacking it in the JavaScript isn't a sufficient solution.

How can I stop the site being overridden by these OS-level changes?

Thanks!